# Angular Material Stepper: show only current and next step in stepper-header

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am using the [Angular Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)(v13.x.x) in horizontal orientation and linear mode.

By default the stepper-header shows all the steps available. However I would like it to only show the active step, the step before and the step after. (And have this shift when I trigger `stepper.next()` or `stepper.previous()`).

Current situation with 2 as active step:
[image]

Wanted situation with 2 as active step:
[image]

It's important that all 5 steps keep working as they are. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum that I managed to achieve in solving this issue is to display the **current** and **next steps**. Here is the CSS code for this:

```
::ng-deep {
  // Hide inactive steps and their lines
  .mat-step-header[aria-selected="false"],
  .mat-step-header[aria-selected="false"] + .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    visibility: collapse;
  }

  // Except for the next one
  .mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"] + .mat-stepper-horizontal-line + .mat-step-header {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Wz3.png).

Comment: I just noticed, that in Chromium `visibility: collapse` property can work incorrectly. So you can use `display: none` and `display: inherit` accordingly instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that `::ng-deep` is deprecated and that using it disables view-encapsulation, which is core feature of Angular. See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep.